# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que las funciones anden y se soliciten los datos al usuario?

Tags: javascript, poo, funciones, condiciones, switch

Quise probar las funciones en este código y no pude pero no entiendo que es lo que hago mal... llamé a las funciones en distintas partes del código y no se si debí agrupar las dos funciones en una sola, pero lo cierto es que no lo gro hacer que funcione el pedir datos al usuario...

```
class Armas{
    constructor(id,modelo,calibre,año,precio,stock){
        this.id=id;
        this.modelo=modelo;
        this.calibre=calibre;
        this.año=año;
        this.precio=precio;
        this.stock=stock;
    }   
    salidaArma(){
        return this.modelo+" "+this.calibre+" año "+this.año+"\n$"+this.precio
    }
}

let arma1=new Armas(125,"Colt 1911","45mm","1998",50000,15);
let arma2=new Armas(524,"Glock 17","40mm","2020",125000,10);
let arma3=new Armas(566,"Bersa ThunderPro","9mm","2020",47000,25);
let arma4=new Armas(894,"Taurus38Spc","38mm","2021",55000,25);

let entradaUsuario=parseInt(prompt("Ingrese N° Item:\n1)Colt 1911\n2)Glock 17\n3)Bersa\n4)Taurus\n0)Salir"))
function serieArmas(entradaUsuario){
    switch (entradaUsuario) {
        case 1:
            return arma1.salidaArma(serieArmas);
        case 2:
            return arma2.salidaArma(serieArmas);    
        case 3:
            return arma3.salidaArma(serieArmas);
        case 4:
            return arma4.salidaArma(serieArmas);
        default:
            alert("El item ingresado no esta disponible");
            break;
    }
}

function solicitarDatos(){
    while (entradaUsuario!=0) {
        if(entradaUsuario<=4){
            alert("Item selecionado: "+serieArmas(entradaUsuario));
        }
        else{alert("item incorrecto")}
        entradaUsuario=parseInt(prompt("Ingrese N° Item:\n1)Colt 1911\n2)Glock 17\n3)Bersa\n4)Taurus\n0)Salir"))   
    }

solicitarDatos()

serieArmas()
```

Comment: Es correcto que realices funciones, pero en este caso la funcion solicitarDatos() es incorrecta ya que no estas cerrando con }

Comment: es correcto @Jorgesys quizás se me pasó por error cuando publiqué, pero aun cerrando con la llave adecuadamente, no anda el código...

Comment: estas llamando serieArmas() no es necesario, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es correcto que realices funciones,
Hay un error al llamar `serieArmas()` ya que este método pretende recibir el valor de la entrada de usuario, únicamente debes llamar `solicitarDatos()` ya que sería la entrada a tu aplicación.

La función `solicitarDatos()` es incorrecta ya que no estas cerrando con `}`, en cuanto a el código los "semicolon" en JavaScript no requiere estrictamente punto y coma.

```js
class Armas{
    constructor(id,modelo,calibre,año,precio,stock){
        this.id=id;
        this.modelo=modelo;
        this.calibre=calibre;
        this.año=año;
        this.precio=precio;
        this.stock=stock;
    }   
    salidaArma(){
        return this.modelo+" "+this.calibre+" año "+this.año+"\n$"+this.precio;
    }
}

let arma1=new Armas(125,"Colt 1911","45mm","1998",50000,15);
let arma2=new Armas(524,"Glock 17","40mm","2020",125000,10);
let arma3=new Armas(566,"Bersa ThunderPro","9mm","2020",47000,25);
let arma4=new Armas(894,"Taurus38Spc","38mm","2021",55000,25);

let entradaUsuario=parseInt(prompt("Ingrese N° Item:\n1)Colt 1911\n2)Glock 17\n3)Bersa\n4)Taurus\n0)Salir"));
function serieArmas(entradaUsuario){
    switch (entradaUsuario) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            return arma1.salidaArma(serieArmas);
        case 2:
            return arma2.salidaArma(serieArmas);    
        case 3:
            return arma3.salidaArma(serieArmas);
        case 4:
            return arma4.salidaArma(serieArmas);
        default:
            alert("El item ingresado no esta disponible");
            break;
    }
}

function solicitarDatos(){
    while (entradaUsuario!=0) {
        if(entradaUsuario<=4){
            alert("Item selecionado: "+serieArmas(entradaUsuario));
        }
        else{alert("item incorrecto")}
        entradaUsuario=parseInt(prompt("Ingrese N° Item:\n1)Colt 1911\n2)Glock 17\n3)Bersa\n4)Taurus\n0)Salir"));   
    }
}
    

solicitarDatos();

   // serieArmas();
```